# Get a message if insert into table works

Tags: database

The code I wrote that uses `db_insert()` and `db_merge()` works great. I can populate the database table well (also using a post http). Now I want to get a success/fail message.

How do I show a message after executing a query?

Comment: I've tried to count rows before and after insert (merge) and compare if difference but there's a problem somewhere (it always shows : user exists (even if it's not true) and the insert works after that message (or before) !!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) to display a message in the browser, this can be marked as a status', 'warning' or 'error' message.

If you want to debug your code, the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module is recommended and provides the [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) function. Besides being able to print a simple message, `dpm()` also allows to display an array or object quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

You show messages using [`drupal_set_message()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7):

> Sets a message to display to the user.
>
> Messages are stored in a session variable and displayed in page.tpl.php via the $messages theme variable.

Comment: the thing is I know how to show messages, I want just to show them in a condition (if insert or not)

Comment: Use a `try...catch` around the `db_insert`, that's the best way

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the status of the insert, perhaps a more suitable function for your use case is [`drupal_write_record`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7)

> **Return value**
>
> If the record insert or update failed, returns FALSE. If it succeeded, returns [SAVED_NEW](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/SAVED_NEW/7) or [SAVED_UPDATED](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/constant/SAVED_UPDATED/7), depending on the operation performed.

To update a record, you need to have the `'primary key field name' => 'value'` in the `$record` (2nd) parameter passed to the function. As well as that, you need to pass the `$primary_keys` (3rd) parameter which is a simple array of your primary key field names without the values. If it's just a single primary key (`id` for example), then you can pass it as a string as well.

If you omit the 3rd parameter `$primary_keys` then it's going to perform a `db_insert` otherwise it does a `db_update`.

In fact, as you follow the function along, it shows you exactly how to evaluate whether the `db_insert` or `db_update` were a success or not. So I won't be covering it here.

Comment: You mean i've te replace the db_insert and db_merge by drupal_write_record ?

Comment: I've just replace db_insert by drupal_write_record, but it insert even if the actual record exists on database (duplicating problem) did you know how to avoid this ? any condition ?

Comment: @Mitch _but it insert even if the actual record exists on database_ means that you haven't got your primary keys quite right. If you had, you would simply receive an exception for trying to insert into a duplicate into a column with a unique constraint

Comment: The primary key i used is a serial key so it's not a good key to make difference between two records (even if it's the same record) because this pk is auto increment so those records are considered as "different" just because id is different (but in fact it's the same record) how to put another key to be "the difference maker" ?? (like key for db_merge)

Comment: @Mitch check the edit, hope I understood you correctly, and it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

by the way I've solved my problem by try catch as @clive adviced me on comment,

The`drupal_write_record` works as well so thank you Beebee

If it can helps, here is the part of code with the try catch :

```
try{
$uid_courant = db_query("SELECT (MAX(uid))+1 as max_id FROM {users}")->fetchCol();
$create_user = db_merge('users')
    ->key(array('name'=> $data["username_client"],'uid'=>'uid'))
    ->fields(array(
        'uid'=> $uid_courant,
        'name'=>$data["username_client"],
        'pass'=>$data['password_cl'],
        'mail'=>$data["mail_cl"],
        'created'=>time()
        ))
->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e){
$user_existe = array('code'=>'1','error'=>'1');
}
```

Here the code insert a new user only if there's no user with same username on table "users", if not it returns an error. and in the same time i'm inserting the same user on anotre custom table i've created this table is called "client" and do same verifications.

Thank you all.